# How can I get the previous month data in ORACLE, if I have to run the sql script every month?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my version of SQL code:

```
select HISTORY_ID,START_DTM FROM LEM.LEM_ALERT_HISTORY 
where MONTH from START_DTM = add_months (sysdate, -1) ;
```

Also, what if the current month is Jan, how can I get the data from last year's Dec?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `add_months()` will give December if the sysdate month is January refer this link https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/datetime-functions/oracle-add_months-function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
select HISTORY_ID
     , START_DTM
  from LEM.LEM_ALERT_HISTORY
 where START_DTM >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM') AND START_DTM < LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1))
```

If the current month is January it will return the data from December last year

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I want to know ensure one more thing, since the sql script is set to excute every month automatically. Therefore, if I run the script today (9 of aug), then I can get the data of whole July. 

and If it is now Jan 2022, then I can get the data from whole Dec 2021.  Am I right?

Comment: @benjjm Yes, that's right. if you run the script today (9 of aug), then you can get the data of whole July and If it is now Jan 2022, then you can get the data from whole Dec 2021.

Comment: This will exclude any data after midnight on the last day of the month. It would be better to do `where START_DTM >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) and START_DTM < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')`

Comment: Do not use `between` for dates in Oracle, because `date` is actually a datetime